# php foreach as change variable names

Tags: php, variables, foreach, variable-names

Can I change the variable names used in foreach in PHP?

```
foreach ($sql2htmlLists as $kkkkk => $vvvvv){
```

instead of the default:

```
foreach ($sql2htmlLists as $key => $value){
```

Thank you

Comment: Why you can't ?

Comment: Simple answer = YES. ___Obvious Question: Why didn't you just try it and see for yourself___

Comment: The variable names you use for `as $key => $value` are completely up to you. You are actually creating 2 new variables in that command so call them anything you like ___that makes sense! so others can understand your code___ So `$kkkkk => $vvvvv` is probably not the best naming convention :)

Comment: You are right RiggsFolly - I posted before test before my architecture is too slow - I have to wait couple of minutes before see the result... Welcome in the XIV century ^^ hihi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use whatever you want

```
foreach ($sql2htmlLists as $key => $value){

}
```

But i suggest you to use proper variables.And try to unset that variables at the end of loop to get out from conflicts.